# Assign randomly tasks to groups

Tags: r, random, dplyr

I have 5 groups:

```
groups <- as.tribble( ~ group, 
                     "group_1",
                     "group_2",
                     "group_3",
                     "group_4",
                     "group_5")
```

And I want to randomly assign each of them to a task:

```
tasks <- as.tribble( ~ task, 
                    "task_1",
                    "task_2",
                    "task_3",
                    "task_4",
                    "task_5")
```

Comment: Did you check with `sample` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Coming from a place of two data frames with the same number of rows, using dplyr, I would do this:

```
inner_join(
  mutate(groups, rand = sample(n())),
  mutate(tasks, rand = sample(n())),
  by = "rand"
) %>%
select(-rand)
```

This will match each row from `groups` to each row from `tasks` in a random way, but ensuring that each group and each task is included. It will generalize up just fine in case you have more columns in either data frame. It assumes you have the same number of rows in each---if you do not, all the rows from the smaller data frame will be included, and a random subsample of rows from the larger data frame.

If you want something else, please be more specific about the characteristics of your random process.

Comment: Setting `inner_join(..., by = "rand", keep = FALSE)` will cause `rand` to be dropped after you are done with it.

Comment: @muadiib is that a new or dev version thing? I'm on `dplyr` 0.8.0.1, which is pretty current, and it looks like `keep = FALSE` is only implemented for `nest_join`. I don't see any mention of it in the NEWS file on Github.

Comment: Sure enough, you are right. `keep` only works for `nest_join`.